# Solve the system $\begin{cases}a+2n=-8\\b+an=9\\bn=-9\end{cases}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve the system $$\begin{cases}a+2n=-8\\b+an=9\\bn=-9\end{cases}$$
The only real solution is $a=-2,b=3,n=-3$. I am really confused because I can't solve it. My idea was to express $b$ and $n$ in terms of $a$ and then plug into the last equation $$bn=-9$$ From the first equation $$n=\dfrac{-8-a}{2}=-\dfrac{a+8}{2}$$ and from the second $$b=9-an=9+a\cdot\dfrac{a+8}{2}=\dfrac{a^2+8a+18}{2}$$ Is there anything simpler?

Comment: Do you plan to stop editing your question?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, No, I was thinking about editing it the whole day. Bruh. And then there would be downvotes

Comment: Eliminate $n$ and get $9 a = (b - 9) b$, $ b^3 - 9 b^2 + 72 b = 162$. The cubic in $b$ has a single real root, $b=3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can deduce from the second equation that $b=9-an$. So, the system becomes$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}a+2n=-8\\(9-an)n=-9.\end{array}\right.$$Now, $a=-8-2n$, and so all you need to do is to solve the equation $\bigl(9-(-8-2n)n\bigr)n=-9$, which is equivalent to $2 n^3+8 n^2+9 n+9=0$. Using the rational roots theorem, you can deduce that $-3$ is a root of this equation. And, since$$2 n^3+8 n^2+9 n+9=(n+3) \left(2 n^2+2 n+3\right),$$there are no other real roots.

Answer (score 3):

Multiplying the first equation with $n$ and taking difference with the second, gives $$\tag{$\ast$}b - 2n^2 = 9 + 8n.$$
From the third equation, we can conclude $b = -9/n$. (It must be nonzero.)
Putting this in $(\ast)$ gives $$-\frac{9}{n} - 2n^2 = 9 + 8n.$$
Rearranging this gives us $$2n^3 + 8n^2 + 9n + 9 = 0.$$
The [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) gives us a small amount of possible rational roots to check for. One checks that $n = -3$ works. Factoring the polynomial using the root $(n + 3)$, we see that it has no other real root.

Plugging this in your third equation gives $b = 3$. It is now straightforward to find $a$.